# Can't change mountpoint in docker compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-volume

I am creating simple app. I have started to use docker to run MySQL server. But I can't change mounting point.

First, I created this docker-compose file:

```yaml
version: "3.8"

services:
  database:
    image: mysql:8.0
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: "main"
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: "test"
      MYSQL_USER: "api"
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: "test"
      MYSQL_TCP_PORT: 17001
    ports:
      - "17001:17001"
    volumes:
      - database:/var/lib/mysql/data

volumes:
  database:
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
      type: none
      o: bind
      device: "./Database"
```

But it doesn't changes mounting point. To check if data have mounted in different place, I usually use `docker volume inspect`. Then I used something like this:

```yaml
...
  volumes:
    - "path/to/folder"
```

But it also doesn't work. What I need to do?

Comment: What do you mean by "*... it doesn't changes mounting point*"? If I change `- database:/var/lib/mysql/data` to, e.g., `- database:/var/lib/mysql/data_foo` (and redeploy the compose file), then the mount-point has changed. Please [edit] the post and clarify.